# Let G be a group. If order of the element in the group $G$ is prime

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group. If order of the element in the group $G$ is prime ($G$ is not a $p$-group, order of the elements are different prime). Is it true that every element of order $p$ are in the same conjugacy class of $G$?

Comment: The dihedral group of order $10$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Or a cyclic group of a order $6$....

Comment: Please be clearer and more informative in your titles. Your two questions  so far are identical except for using `G` instead of `$G$` on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Not all elements of order 5 in the alternating group $A_5$ are conjugate.